# Using a UUID for logging across all python files in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to modularize a small Python script so I can grow it. When it was super small I created a `correlationKey` (which was a UUID) global variable that I used when I logged so that I could easily find logs pertaining to just this one run. How can I share this globally across all my files but just for this one process? After the end or the script exits I don't want it to keep logging with that UUID anymore. Is a thread safe variable the way to go? I am pretty new to python so trying to figure out what the best way for a newbie would be.

I have set up my own function called logging that does what I want, now I just need to figure out how to utilize it so all the files and functions that call log() will get the same correlationKey.

Edit:

I am logging right now to my Splunk instance over HEC. So I had a custom implementation for the logging. It is pretty simple.

Right now have this set up:

```
def log(message):
    payload = {}
    payload.update({"source":"c19"})
    payload.update({"host":"server"})
    payload.update({"time": time.time() })
    message = "timestamp=\"" + str(datetime.now()) + "\" correlationKey=" + correlationKey + " message=\"" + str(message) + "\""
    payload.update({"event":message})
    #print(payload)
    r = requests.post(splunkHost, headers=splunkAuthHeader, json=payload, verify=False)
    #print(r.text)
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in python logging module? You can configure the logger object to tag output with time&date so you know the run, and link the logger objects together. As the documentation says: `Multiple calls to logging.getLogger('someLogger') return a reference to the same logger object. This is true not only within the same module, but also across modules as long as it is in the same Python interpreter process`

Comment: Hello. No I am not. I am going to be logging to my Splunk HEC so I have something custom set up. Added some edits above.

Comment: Doesn't the [Splunk documentation](https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/developapps/addsupport/logging/loggingsplunkextensions/) say that it uses the python logging module? `The Splunk platform uses the Python logging module to provide a comprehensive logging system for your scripts`

Comment: You may also find this of use: https://pypi.org/project/splunk-handler/

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately it doesn't answer my question here. I need some type of UUID to easily correlate a transaction/process. This just helps me log to Splunk, which isn't an issue here right now but could make it easier.